# How to check whether a record is deletable using Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I want to check whether a record in a database table is deletable or not using Entity Framework. If the record's primary key is being used as foreign key in different tables, then this record is not deletable.

I know I can run entity framework's `Remove` Function to delete a record and to see whether I can get any SQL exception with specific number. But if it successful, it will delete the record entirely. This is not what I want. I just want to to check whether the record is deletable or not by looking at other tables with foreign key relationships.

A very straight forward approach might be to use navigation properties one by one. But I want to make it more generic. Any idea will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Load all related ends of your `originalEntity` that are pointing at it via foreign keys (not the navigation properties from it, but vice versa):

```
IEnumerable<IRelatedEnd> relEnds = ((IEntityWithRelationships) originalEntity).RelationshipManager.GetAllRelatedEnds();

 foreach (IRelatedEnd relatedEnd in relEnds)
 {
   if (relatedEnd is EntityReference)
   {
      continue;
   }

   relatedEnd.Load();

   if (relatedEnd.CreateSourceQuery().OfType<EntityObject>().Any())
   {
     string exceptionMessage = string.Format("{0} cannot be deleted, because {1} refers to it",
                                                              originalEntity.GetType().Name, 
                                                              relatedEnd.CreateSourceQuery().OfType<EntityObject>().First().GetType().Name);

     throw new Exception(exceptionMessage);
   }
}
```

For more details you may want to have a look at RelatedEnd class at MSDN:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.dataclasses.relatedend%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

```
// Collection of entities, you need these when iterating through entity's related ends
public class EntityCollection<TEntity> : RelatedEnd

// Models a relationship end with multiplicity 1.
public abstract class EntityReference : RelatedEnd
```

Comment: Looks like a viable approach, but as such it doesn't work for the `DbContext` API. Esp. the part `OfType<EntityObject>` can't work with POCOs.

Comment: You can retrieve `ObjectContext` from `DbContext` like following: `IObjectContextAdapter adapter = (IObjectContextAdapter)dbContextInstance;`
`ObjectContext objectContext = adapter.ObjectContext;`

Comment: Be careful using `relatedEnd.Load();` because it gets all the data from the database and then does the `relatedEnd.CreateSourceQuery().OfType<EntityObject>().Any()` and if you have a large amount of rows then this will cause sever performance issues.